# In Lua, how does a = Account:new{balance = 0} work or is it a typo?

Tags: lua

On the Lua website https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html , there is this section of code

```
function Account:new (o)
  o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
  setmetatable(o, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end

a = Account:new{balance = 0}
a:deposit(100.00)
```

Shouldn't the line `a = Account:new{balance = 0}` be written as `a = Account:new(balance = 0)` with the brackets being replaced with parentheses because it is a function?

Comment: `Account:new(balance = 0)` would be a syntax error (you can't put an equals sign there).

Comment: @immibis This code is copied straight from the Lua website.

Comment: Where did you see `Account:new(balance = 0)` on the Lua website?

Comment: @immibis after the 5th paragraph on the webpage sited on the first line of my question.

Comment: No, that contains `Account:new{balance = 0}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Account:new { balance = 0 }` is syntactic sugar for `Account:new({ balance = 0 })`.

This is, if the only argument passed to a function is a table *constructor*, or string *literal*, then the parenthesis can be omitted.

The most common place you'll see this is in lines with [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require):

```
local env = require 'env'
```

This is discussed in [§3.4.10 – `Function Calls`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) of the [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/):

> A call of the form `f{fields}` is syntactic sugar for `f({fields})`; that is, the argument list is a single new table. A call of the form `f'string'` (or `f"string"` or `f[[string]]`) is syntactic sugar for `f('string')`; that is, the argument list is a single literal string.